# set a password in an Excel file in python

Tags: python, excel, encryption, passwords, xlsxwriter

I want to develop Excel download api, which encrypts the Excel file itself using Python, as fastapi.
I want to create a data frame of the pandas as an Excel file, set the password, and deliver it to the client. When the client opens the downloaded Excel file, a popup will open where you enter the password.
xlsxwriter or openpyxl only encrypts the sheet, not the entire file. Win32 has the disadvantage of not working properly with mac.

Is there any other good way?

Comment: Why do you want to encypt it? It looks like you just want to protect the Excel from being read with a password. Why the encryption?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [msoffice-crypt](https://github.com/herumi/msoffice) tool to encrypt the file after it is created. That is what is recommended in the [XlsxWriter docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/faq.html#q-can-i-password-protect-an-xlsxwriter-xlsx-file).